# Does Big Bad Voodoo stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

If there are multiple WDs in party and they all use the [Big Bad Voodoo](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/big-bad-voodoo) skill:

1) If they have the same rune, does the bonus stack?

2) If they have different runes, do I get bonus from all runes while standing in the area of effect?

Answer (score 4):

I played with another WD recently and we both had *Big Bad Voodoo* with *Slam Dance* rune. So to answer your first question:

No, the bonus doesn't stack. With 1 or 2 *Big Bad Voodoos*, you will only get 1 bonus.

I will check with different runes later, but I'm pretty sure you will get both bonuses

Answer (score 2):

The base stats of BBV won't stack but the runes do stack, so if you're with more WD's in a party watch out using different runes on it. Its like the mantras from the monk. Mantra of evasion gives you 17% dodge, if there's another monk with the same mantra your effective dodge still is just increased by 17% and not by 34%.